# Can't add jvmArgs using add(), why?

Tags: gradle

Can anyone explain why the first sample working while the second does nothing?

```
test {
    jvmArgs '-Xdebug',
            '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000'
}

test {
    jvmArgs.add('-Xdebug')
    jvmArgs.add('-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000')
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in the second example [this](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#getJvmArgs()) method is invoked. You get the list, modify it but the changes are not reflected to settings - *read only access*. In the first example [this](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#setJvmArgs(java.lang.Iterable)) method is invoked and arguments passed are set.

Here's the explanation, a copy of the list is returned (it's for safety, security reasons - mutable types should be always returned as a copy)

```
public List<String> getJvmArgs() {
   List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (Object extraJvmArg : extraJvmArgs) {
      args.add(extraJvmArg.toString());
   }
   return args;
}
```

Comment: That's explain it. Can you elaborate why read only access? I'm new to Groovy, in java you get a reference to a list and you can change it however you want.

Comment: That's not a matter of groovy, java. See updated answer.

Comment: Maddeningly, different tasks which allow specifying JVM args operate differently, for `JavaCompile` it's `options.compilerArgs.add('--enable-preview')`, for `JavaExec` `jvmArgs.add('--enable-preview')` will work and for `Test` it's simply `jvmArgs('--enable-preview')`. All do the same thing, adding the argument to the existing set of JVM arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problematic with the normal command line arguments using Gradle as well -- Even to the extent that *Example 1* works and *Example 2* will fail to add the extra argument:

- `runArgs` is set in the main build.gradle

As follows:

```
 ext {
     runArgs = [ '-server=localhost', '-port=8080' ];
 }
```

Simply appending to the command line appears *challenging* (see below).

---

**Example 1**:

```
debug.doFirst(){

//  ... <snip> ...

        //  command line arguments
        //
    println "      debug args (a):  ${args}."
    runArgs.add( "-memo=${project.name}:debug" );
    args = runArgs;
    println "      debug args (b):  ${args}."


}
```

Output is correct, shows "-memo" parameter is added but also the passed-in `args` have been replaced by the script variable using this approach.

```
debug args (a):  [-server, localhost, -port, 8080 ].
debug args (b):  [-server=localhost, -port=8080, -memo=Client:debug].
```

---

**Example 2**:

```
debug.doFirst(){

//  ... <snip> ...

        //  command line arguments
        //
    println "      debug args (a):  ${args}."
    args.add( "-memo=${project.name}:debug" );
    println "      debug args (b):  ${args}."


}
```

Output (*correctly*?) shows there was no `add()`, *per* answer: [from Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29965111/108350) above.

```
debug args (a):  [-server, localhost, -port, 8080 ].
debug args (b):  [-server, localhost, -port, 8080 ].
```

I've posted this example to show that there may be alternatives to accepting the *status quo*, i expect the `jvmArgs` to work in a similar pattern.  I didn't find examples for adding extra debug specific arguments (say).  So here is one.

I also saw in a couple of places (on-line and books), examples such as:

```
jvmArgs.add( "-DAPPLICATION_LOCATION=City" );
jvmArgs.add( "-DSERVER_HOST=localhost" );
```

Which as we now understand, do not work.

The use-case I set-out to implement is for the sub-project `build.gradle` Script to supply missing arguments and/or script specific parameters (e.g. as in the debug run example).  It is clear to me that if you want to do this, the script will need to either *replace* the command line or analyse the `args` passed-in and then wrinkle-out the defaults by some mechanism.

Hopefully the example will give others more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this hack is working:

```
def jvmArgsCopy = jvmArgs
jvmArgsCopy.add("-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g")
jvmArgs = jvmArgsCopy
```

Answer (score 0):

And to add to this here it is in Kotlin gradle

```
    val jvmArgsCopy: ArrayList<String> = jvmArgs as ArrayList<String>
    jvmArgsCopy.add("-Xdebug")
    jvmArgsCopy.add("-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=4000")
    jvmArgs = jvmArgsCopy
```