# Gradle won't pass args to Java main

Tags: java, gradle, args

I run this command:

```
./gradlew BL_generate -Pserverversion=10.3
```

for this Gradle task:

```
task BL_generate(type: JavaExec) {
    if (project.hasProperty('serverversion')) {
    args(serverversion)
    }
    dependsOn resources_cleaner_bl
    //dependsOn BL_generate_warmup
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m","-Xmx1024m"]
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties['isDummyRun'] = 'false'
    main = "com.waze.routing.automation.runners.BaselineGeneratorRunner"
}
```

and my Java main is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        BaselineGeneratorRunner baselineGeneratorRunner = new BaselineGeneratorRunner();
        generateResponses(baselineGeneratorRunner);
        baselineGeneratorRunner.aggregate();

        if (args.length > 0) {
             globalSettings.blServerVersion = args[0];
             System.out.println("args: "+args[0]);
        }
    }
```

How come I don't see this print in the console?

Comment: Here you can find an example that works perfectly fine: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/30996742

Comment: exactly what I did, so i don't understand why mine won't print

Comment: I know it's very similar, just added it for you to compare. Debug your script, is the property really passed? Are arguments set? And so on..

Comment: is there a better way to debug other than prints?

Comment: You can connect a remote debugger. Google for that.

Comment: @EladBenda2 ... You may find this working example posted under the same question helpful: [**Can't add jvmArgs using add(), why?** -- Example with `args`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48738109/108350).